# Pivot with multiple dynamic rows

Tags: pivot

How do i get this?

[image: PIV B4]

to look like this:

[image: PIV After]

my create and insert code :

```
Create Table Countries
(
    Country nvarchar(50),
    Town nvarchar(50),
    City nvarchar(50)
)
GO

Insert into Countries values ('USA','New Jersy','New York')
Insert into Countries values ('USA','houst','Houston')
Insert into Countries values ('USA','Dally','Dallas')

Insert into Countries values ('India','hyder','Hyderabad')
Insert into Countries values ('India','Bang','Bangalore')
Insert into Countries values ('India','Del','New Delhi')
Insert into Countries values ('India','townin','India Town')

Insert into Countries values ('UK','chelsea','London')
Insert into Countries values ('UK','sunderland','Birmingham')
Insert into Countries values ('UK','United','Manchester')
```

Current pivot code:

```
Select Country, town1, City1, town2, City2, town3, City3, town4, City4, town5, City5
From
(
Select Country, City, 'City'+ cast(row_number() over(partition by Country order by Country) as varchar(10)) ColumnSequence,
Town, 'Town'+ cast(row_number() over(partition by Country order by Country) as varchar(10)) ColumnSequence2 
from Countries
) Temp
pivot
(
max(City)
for ColumnSequence in (City1, City2, City3, City4, City5) 
) Piv
pivot
(
max(Town)
for ColumnSequence2 in (town1, town2, town3, town4, town5) 
) Piv
group by Country, town1, City1, town2, City2, town3, City3, town4, City4, 
town5, City5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605913/sql-query-with-multiple-pivot/43612542#43612542

Comment: Wanted to use 1 table and i do not want to explicitly state the table name....is it possible to convert this code

Comment: are you sure you hv posted correct data.Can i hv 2 town in same city,in that how it will arrange.in this link i solve same problem but it do not seem to work in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652187/dynamic-convert-row-to-column-using-group-by/43653194?noredirect=1#comment74477993_43653194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get MAX value of Towns and Cities grouped by Country.

> ```
> SELECT Country, 
>        MAX(town1) Town1, MAX(City1) City1, 
>        MAX(town2) Town2, MAX(City2) City2, 
>        MAX(town3) Town3, MAX(City3) City3, 
>        MAX(town4) Town4, MAX(City4) City4, 
>        MAX(town5) Town5, MAX(City5) City5
> FROM (
>       SELECT Country, 
>              City, 
>              'City' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Country) AS varchar(10)) ColumnSequence,
>              Town, 
>              'Town'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Country) AS varchar(10)) ColumnSequence2 
>       FROM Countries
>      ) Temp
> PIVOT (MAX(City) FOR ColumnSequence IN (City1, City2, City3, City4, City5)) Piv
> PIVOT (MAX(Town) FOR ColumnSequence2 IN (town1, town2, town3, town4, town5)) Piv
> GROUP BY Country
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Country | Town1     | City1     | Town2      | City2      | Town3  | City3      | Town4  | City4      | Town5 | City5
> :------ | :-------- | :-------- | :--------- | :--------- | :----- | :--------- | :----- | :--------- | :---- | :----
> India   | hyder     | Hyderabad | Bang       | Bangalore  | Del    | New Delhi  | townin | India Town | null  | null 
> UK      | chelsea   | London    | sunderland | Birmingham | United | Manchester | null   | null       | null  | null 
> USA     | New Jersy | New York  | houst      | Houston    | Dally  | Dallas     | null   | null       | null  | null 
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ab9580cbf0ae8e3d3083efb09d1c4372)*